# Find holes in sequential MongoDB field

Tags: mongodb, sequence, nosql

I have MongoDB collection with **sequential integer field**.

I need to find best approach to find "holes" in that sequence that happens due to records deletion.

For example if I have collection with these documents:

```
{ _id: "aab", seq: 1 ... }, { _id: "aac", seq: 2 ... }, { _id: "aad", seq: 4 ... }
```

The next insert I do, needs to be:

```
{ _id: "aae", seq: 3 ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can create a [MongoDB Stored Function](http://dirolf.com/2010/04/05/stored-javascript-in-mongodb-and-pymongo.html) to achieve this.

You can create a JavaScript Stored function which store's the "Sequence Numbers" of the document, getting deleted in some collection "StoreDeletedSequenceNumCollection".

Whenever you perform a Delete operation on the collection, make sure you call the "Stored Function " which actually stores the Sequence Number of the Document which is getting deleted in the collection "StoreDeletedSequenceNumCollection".

```
db.system.js.save( { _id: "DeletedSeqNum", 
                    value: function (seqNum) { 
                             db.StoreDeletedSequenceNumCollection.insert(
                                 { _id : seqNum}); return 1 ; } 
                   } 
                );
```

When you are inserting a document, you can check if there are any sequence numbers present in the "StoreDeletedSequenceNumCollection", If present you can get the MINIMUM Sequence number from it and can use for insertion, Else if the "StoreDeletedSequenceNumCollection" is empty, then you can get the "MAXIMUM"  sequence number form your actual collection and can use " MAXIMUM + 1" as a sequence number for insertion.